# Changing my audio codec change my audio level

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have an issue with a ffmpeg compression. I have severals video clip (video in H264, container .mp4, audio in wav).

For broadcast on specific devices,  the company that manage the broadcast has to concatenate the videos and change the codec. I just realized that when they do their stuff, the audio volume level changes too. I asked them to give me their code so I can have a look. After some research, I do not understand how the volume lvel can change. Can someone help me ?
Here's the code :

```
# generate concat string with all clips
#
concatstring="concat:"
index=0
for i in $*; do
   concatstring+="final"$index".mpg|"
   let "index=index+1"
done

concatstring=${concatstring:0:-1}

#
# concat all clips in video.wmv to fit in a 15Mbytes or 30Mbytes file maximum
# $ratio contain ratio like  vga:640x480 or hd720:1280x720
# so with a 90s clip size max, we have ~1100k or ~2400k for bit rate (this is a bit less cause sound space around 200k)
#
#avconv -i "$concatstring" -c copy final.mpg

if [ $ratio = "hd720" ];
then
 avconv -y -i "$concatstring" -threads auto -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 -ac 2 -b:a 96k -b:v $compress -s:v $ratio video.wmv
 #avconv -y -i final.mpg -threads auto -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 -ac 2 -b:a 96k -b:v $compress -s:v $ratio video.wmv
fi

if [ $ratio = "vga" ];
then
 avconv -y -i "$concatstring" -threads auto -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 -ac 2  -ar 44100 -b:v 760k -minrate:v 760k  -b:a 90k  -s:v vga  -r 25 video.wmv
 #avconv -y -i final.mpg -threads auto -vcodec wmv2 -q:v 8 -acodec wmav2 -ac 2 -b:a 80k -ar 44100 -s:v $ratio -r 24 video.wmv
fi

if [ $ratio = "vgabis" ];
then
 avconv -y -i "$concatstring" -threads auto -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 -ac 2  -ar 44100 -b:v 760k -minrate:v 760k  -b:a 90k  -s:v vga  -r 25 video.wmv
 #avconv -y -i final.mpg -threads auto -vcodec wmv2 -q:v 8 -acodec wmav2 -ac 2 -b:a 80k -ar 44100 -s:v vga -r:v 24 video.wmv
fi
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are all the input audio streams stereo?